# Using jquery to pull from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

```
http://localhost:2000/WebService/Handler.ashx?d=ck
```

Response when viewing URL:

```
{"Status":"OK","Message":"0","Info":"(none)"}
```

Using JQuery how do I pull from that? I get how you do POST and sending but little lost has to how to pull from that. Do I use GET?

Am I doing something like $.get("URL HERE"...?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Unless your webservice returns CORS headers or proper JSONP, it won't work if localhost:2000 isn't the same domain AND port as the page requesting the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url:"...",
    dateType: "json", // <=== you expect "JSON" string
    success: function(data){ 
        alert(data.Status); // Extract the data from the response.
        alert(data.Message);
        alert(data.Info);            
    }        
});
```

Or the shorthand `getJSON` function:

```
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
    data.Status;
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function to retreive your JSON response:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:2000/WebService/Handler.ashx?d=ck',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) { 
      console.log(data); 
      console.log('Status: ' + data.Status); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function of jquery.

```
 $.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback
});
```

Or this way...

```
 $.getJSON('ajax/test.json', {data: data },function(data) {
      // do as needed
 });
```